# Need tap gesture method after UIwebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate invocation

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview, gesture

My Problem is I have a webView inside the UIView and UIView have tap gesture and web view class having delegate of UIWebView.

My problem is when i tap on a link it first call tap then `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` . So i need to prevent calling of code which is written for tap on view.

Any one having any idea............

> **Edit**

code for web view delegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        self.isAnyLinkTapped = YES;
        RELEASE(webURL);
        webURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request.URL absoluteString]] retain];
        NSArray *urlCoponents = [[request.URL absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        if([urlCoponents count]>0)
        {
//Some code here

}
}

}
```

i have add tap gesture like this

```
_tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
```

and on tapping below code is invoking.

```
- (void) tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

    touchPointLocationForTap  = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

    [(WebViewController*)delegate setIsScreenTouched:YES];

    BOOL isThereAnySelection = [self isThereAnyTextSelectionOnWebView];

    if (!isThereAnySelection)
        [self performSelector:@selector(sendTapEventToWebController) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.2];  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post some code so that everybody can understand..

By the way-

you can identify view which was touched by using this condition

```
if([[touches view] isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){
//Do whatever you want to do with webview
}else{
//Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Ok i have edit my question. I need to give touch on web view but need to prevent the tap when any link is clicked but tapped: method calls before shouldStartLoadWithRequest:.

Comment: as you have added tap gesture on UIView which is superview of your webview always tapped: will be called first. Why you have added tapGuesture? you can directly get if hyperlink is tapped or not in UIWebView.

Comment: tapped is for some other functionalities.

Comment: may I know what kind of functionality?

Comment: When i tap on web view html takes full screen for reading and when other time i tap it shrinks.also page flip animation is there on tap on side of html for showing next page. it is like a html book. now html having some links and when i touch a link it first perform full screen mode then perform link actions.

Comment: hmm I am not able to think any solution for this right now can you send me sample demo of your app with the issue?